# I want to press a key combination in an EWMH compliant window manager and have a terminal appear below my resized Chromium window

Tags: window-manager, openbox, lubuntu, lxde

*This is one of those things that looks like it might have a simple solution but is rather time consuming once you start investigating PyTile, Xnee and the likes.*

*I know, I should just use a tiling window manager etc., but I suppose it can be done in an EWMH compliant window manager (like OpenBox), and I am just hoping somebody already has a working solution.*

Ok, so I want to press a key combination while I am in an OpenBox session (Lubuntu LXDE to be more precise) and have my terminal appear below my then resized Chromium window (say ~60% Chromium and ~40% Terminal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a small script that puts Chromium at 60% of the screen, launches a terminal, and puts it under Chromium:

```
#!/bin/bash

screen_width=` wmctrl -d | awk '{print $9}' | cut -d x -f 1`
screen_height=`wmctrl -d | awk '{print $9}' | cut -d x -f 2`
titlebar=51
browser="Chromium"
terminal_cmd="xterm"

browser_height=$[$screen_height * 60 / 100 - $titlebar]
# unmaximize browser
wmctrl -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz -r "$browser"
wmctrl -r "$browser" -e "0,0,0,$screen_width,$browser_height"

# start terminal and wait till its window has appeared
$terminal_cmd &
sleep 1

# put terminal under browser
terminal_top=$[$screen_height * 60 / 100 + $titlebar]
terminal_height=$[$screen_height * 40 / 100]
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e "0,0,$terminal_top,$screen_width,$terminal_height"
```

You can change some properties (like the terminal and browser used, and the height of the window titlebar). Note that `$browser` is (a part of) the browser (window) title (like "Chromium", "Google Chrome" or "Firefox"), **not** the command to launch the browser.

In case you don't want Chromium to resize, it gets a little trickier, but it can be done by getting the window coordinates with `wmctrl -G -l`.

I don't know how to assign keybindings in OpenBox, and whether it works in that WM, but at least it works in Unity when I run it on the command line.